# How to untrust workspace by default in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Workspace trust interrupts the workflow by opening a dialog after open arbitrary directory.

to trust all directory, simply disable workspace trust feature by start vscode with commandline `--disable-workspace-trust`

But how can I **`UNTRUST`** any directory/workspace **`by default`** without a intrusive dialog? or even better, store that setting persistently?
if I deem it safe I could always trust it afterwards.

---

a side note, devs had stated [this](https://www.theregister.com/2021/07/07/visual_studio_code_workspace_trust/) which is interesting:

> "usage data showed a very low rate of granting trust through the
> passive notification. In user studies, we watched people spend all
> their time thinking they had broken something."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have set the **Restricted Mode as default** for files and workspaces using this security configuration:

[image: Security Configuration]

---

You can add the following lines to your `settings.json`

```
"security.workspace.trust.banner": "never",
"security.workspace.trust.startupPrompt": "never",
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "newWindow",
```

---

Or start a new instance of Visual Studio Code and drag & drop a file into this instance. You will receive the following prompt, where you can tick the *Remember my decision for all workspaces* option.

[image: Remember trust settings as default]

This will add the following line in your `settings.json`:

```
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "newWindow",
```

---

Currently I am using Visual Studio Code 1.59.